# Using Yii1.x model function in external PHP controller outside Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I am working on a Yii1 old website. which is linked with some external PHP controllers. These external controllers provide some common functions that are used between 2 different applications. I have a function in `Yii` model that I want to use in one of the external PHP controller is there a way to do this? Currently, this is done by rewriting MySQL query in the PHP external controller but I don't want to follow this lame practice.

I found this link and I am able to access Yii externally but it's still not very helpful. [Using Yii in 3rd-Party Systems](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration#using-yii-in-3rd-party-systems)

Here's a sample of my code:

```
namespace main\Helpers;

require_once('path/to/yii.php');


Class HelperClass {
 public static function yiisupport($id){
 //   I am able to access Yii variables using
     \Yii::app()->name
 // But how to access the yii model or controller functions? I need something like the follwoing
  $model =  \Yii::app()->YiiModel::model()->findByPK($id);
 }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Yii application first (using config file path) to access its models and controllers as it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration#using-yii-in-3rd-party-systems). Then you can access any model class in your external application just like you would access it in your Yii application, and you can use controller actions as below;

```
$controller = new \YOURController('ACTION_NAME');
$controller->ACTION_NAME();
```

If you have already imported models/controllers in your config file then you will not need to import any class but if you have not then you can import specific model/controller like below;

```
\Yii::import('application.models.MODEL_NAME');
\Yii::import('application.controllers.CONTROLLER_NAME');
```

Check the examples below;

```
namespace main\Helpers;

require_once('path/to/yii.php');
\Yii::createWebApplication('path/to/config.php');

Class HelperClass {
    public static function yiisupport($id){
        // Access Yii variables
        \Yii::app()->name;

        // Access yii model
        $model = \YiiModel::model()->findByPK($id);

        // Access yii controller and its actions
        $controller = new \YiiController('actionCreate');
        $controller->actionCreate();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

As mentioned by @rob006 in the comment below that calling yii controller action outside Yii application is a bad idea, however if you still want to do that, there is a safer way which follows the Yii application lifecycle and this way access filters and `beforeAction()` will be triggered. So you can call controller action in a safer way as below;

```
\Yii::app()->runController('route/to/action');
```

Comment: Running Yii controller outside of Yii app is really bad idea. Calling action methods directly is even worse. You will miss many Yii checks and events (like CSRF protection or `beforeAction()` events, including filters which may restrict access to actions).

Comment: You are right @rob006 that calling controller action outside the Yii application is risky. I have updated the answer and added another method to call controller action described in the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#runController-detail), which is safer and follows Yii application lifecycle.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your reply. My intention of calling yii models is to use existing model function I created using yii and use them in external controller so that I don't have to rewrite the whole thing again in plain MySQL query. I am very lazy person and I like to use centralised code so that I don't have to write code again and again. Thanks for your response. @Maz when I used `Yii::createWebApplication()` it gave me error that i can't create application again. So without using it i was able to use `\yii::app()`. So that's why I was wondering if I can use yii model similarly.

Comment: Alright, I think you may have initialized yii app at some earlier stage in your code that's why got that error. However I hope you got the idea that how to use model and controller in your external app.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have used `createWebApplication()` method in the yii application itself from where I want to use the model method. But yes, I got the idea. Not sure, but I think I need to look for `\Yii::app()->runModel('route/to/action');` method or something similar, I guess.

Comment: Thats good. But there isn't any method like `runModel()`, you can check in the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication).